# The Real Slim Shady

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

Echo the following in as few bytes as possible:

```
I'm Slim Shady. Yes, I'm the real Shady.
All you other Slim Shadys are just imitating.
So, won't the real Slim Shady please stand up?
Please stand up. Please stand up.
```

The following five words must appear **EXACTLY ONCE** in your code:

`I'm`
`Slim`
`Shady`
`real`
`stand`

Comment: Now that stupid song is in my head.

Comment: Is it ok if the program output more than the full text? Ie. enclosing the lyric in parens.

Comment: @Sylwester As long as it follows the rules, you can code it how you want.

Comment: do we have to have new lines in the same places you have them in the example output?

Comment: @Malachi it must match the output exactly, yes.

Answer (score 28):

## Python: 176

```
print"{0}{1}{2}. Yes, {0}{3}{2}.\nAll you other {1}{2}s are just imitating.\nSo, won't {3}{1}{2} p{4}?\nP{4}. P{4}.".format("I'm ","Slim ","Shady","the real ","lease stand up")
```

Naturally, the same idea as other compression solutions (though independently obtained).

Comment: I mistakenly downvoted this one. Sorry. (If you make any change I think I can remove the downvote)

Comment: @edc65: Thanks for the honesty :) I edited the answer.

Comment: You can shave off 3 bytes just by reusing the spaces.`print"{0}{1}{2}. Yes, {0}{3}{2}.\nAll you other{1}{2}s are just imitating.\nSo, won't{3}{1}{2} p{4}?\nP{4}. P{4}.".format("I'm"," Slim"," Shady"," the real","lease stand up")`

Answer (score 25):

**Brainfuck 1923 bytes**

Enjoy...

```
-[------->+<]>.+[-->+<]>++.---[->+++<]>+.
[->+++++<]>-.>-[--->+<]>--.--[--->++++<]
>.---.++++.[->+++++<]>-.>-[--->+<]>--.>+
[----->+++<]>+.-------.+++.+[--->+<]>++.
-----[++>---<]>.++[--->++<]>.--[->+++<]>-.
[->++++<]>+.[--->+<]>----.-[++>---<]>+.
------------.++++[->++<]>+.+[-->+<]>++.---
[->+++<]>+.[->+++++<]>-.---[->++++<]
>.------------.---.--[--->+<]>-.---[----->++<]
>.-------------.----.+++++++++++.[++>---<]
>--.>-[--->+<]>--.>+[----->+++<]>+.-------.
+++.+[--->+<]>++.-----[++>---<]>.>
++++++++++.+++[->+++++<]>.[--->+<]>+..
[++>---<]>--.--[->++++<]>+.----------.++++++.-
[---->+<]>+++.+++++[->+++<]
>.+++++.------------.---.+++++++++++++.
[-->+++++<]>+++.>-[--->+<]>--.--
[--->++++<]>.---.++++.[->+++++<]>-.>-
[--->+I'm<]>--.>+[----->+++<]>+.-------.+++.+
[--->+<]>++.------.+[---->+<]>+++.[->+++<]>+.--
[--->+<]>---.-------------.--[--->+<]>-.-
[--->++<]>.+++++++++++.--.+.
[---Slim->+<]>+++.-[--->++<]>-.++++.----.
+++++++++++.+[->+++<]>++.--[--->+<]
>-.-----------.+++++.-------.--[->+++<]>-.
>++++++++++.>-[--->+<]>--.[--->+<]>--.
[->+++++<]>+.------------.--[->++++<]>-.
--------.-.[++>---<]>++.[->+++<]>-.[---->+
<]>+++.---[->++++<]>.------------.---.--[---
>+<]>-.---[----->Shady++<]>.-------------.-
---.+++++++++++.[++>---<]>--.>-[--->+<]
>--.--[--->++++<]>.---.++++.[->+++++<]
>-.>-[--->+<]>--.>+[----->+++<]>+.-------.
+++.+[--->+<]>++.-[---->+<]>++.[-->+++++++<]
>.----.-------.----.--[--->+<]>--.++++[->+++<]
>.--[--->+<]>-.---[->++++<]>-.+.+[->+++<]
>++.+++++++++++++.----------.-[--->+<]
>-.---[->++++<]>+.-----.[--->++++<]>-.>
++++++++++.[->++++++++<]>.+[--->++++<]
>.---real----.----.--[--->+<]>--.++++[->+++<]
>.--[--->+<]>-.---[->++++<]>-.+.+[->+++<]
>++.+++++++++++++.----------.-[--->+<]>-.---
[->++++<]>+.-----.[->+++++<]>--.++[--->++<]
>.[-->stand+++++<]>.+[--->++++<]>
.-------.----.--[--->+<]>--.++++[->+++<]
>.--[--->+<]>-.---[->++++<]>-.+.+[->+++<]
>++.+++++++++++++.----------.-[--->+<]
>-.---[->++++<]>+.-----.[->+++++<]>--.
```

*Standard Loop Holes*

Comment: Does not include the five words.

Comment: Perhaps scroll right, however i'll edit the post so you don't have too...

Comment: I did scroll but somehow missed the words, sorry.

Comment: how many bytes?

Comment: Am I correct in saying 1923 with the new lines removed?

Comment: I came up with **1918** characters, I don't know that any of these characters are outside the norm where they would tack on extra bytes. I don't know another way of counting Bytes yet so I would say 1918

Answer (score 17):

## Perl, 155

With improvements by [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%c3%bcttner) and [Thaylon](/users/29681):

```
$_="01. Yes, 02X.
All you other1s are just imitating.
So, won't21 p3?
P3. P3.";s/\d/("I'm"," SlimX"," the real","lease stand up")[$&]/ge;s/X/ Shady/g;print
```

Comment: @MartinBüttner Excellent suggestions. Thanks :-)

Comment: You can omit the last ; too.

Comment: Love the "All you other 1s" part

Comment: Shifting around the " " for 157: $_="01. Yes, 032.
All you other1s are just imitating.
So, won't31 p4?
P4. P4.";s/0/I'm/g;s/1/ Slim2/g;s/2/ Shady/g;s/3/ the real/g;s/4/lease stand up/g;print

Comment: Mines so similar now, and I was later, so Ill just delete it. You can get another 2 Byte with: $_="01. Yes, 02X.
All you other1s are just imitating.
So, won't21 p3?
P3. P3.";s/\d/("I'm"," SlimX"," the real","lease stand up")[$&]/ge;s/X/ Shady/g;print

Comment: @Thaylon That's a neat trick with the array replacement. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 12):

### Ruby, 154 bytes

```
$><<"012. Yes, 032.
All you other12s are just imitating.
So, won't312 p4?
P4. P4.".gsub(/\d/){%W{I'm \ Slim \ Shady \ the\ real lease\ stand\ up}[$&.hex]}
```

After helping out a few people with how to split up the filler strings I decided to give their replacement callback idea a go. ;)

Comment: You can save some characters: `#{h+a}` is shorter than `"+h+a+"`, and `#{d+h+a}` is shorter than `"+d+h+a+"`.

Comment: @ProgramFOX o.O ... I'm ashamed to say I only thought of `#{h}#{a}`.

Comment: Can save a few more with `h=" Slim"+a=" Shady"`, and one by replacing `puts ` with `$><<`.

Comment: 154 with `.gsub(/\d/){%W{I'm \ Slim \ Shady \ the\ real lease\ stand\ up}[$&.hex]}`

Comment: @Ventero thanks! :)

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (E6) 165

Just the same in another language

```
alert("012. Yes, 05326All you other12s are just imitating6So, won't5312 p4?\nP4. P4."
.replace(/\d/g,x=>"I'm1 Slim1 Shady1real1lease stand up1 the 1.\n".split(1)[x]))
```

Explanation: replace each single digit in the first string with the corresponding string in the array `["I'm"," Slim"," Shady","real","lease stand up"," the ",".\n"]`

Revised with the new rules here at PPCG (output returned from a function, no constraints about features newer than the challenge), this could be 158. See the snippet

```js
F=
_=>`012. Yes, 0532.
All you other12s are just imitating.
So, won't5312 p4?
P4. P4.`.replace(/\d/g,x=>"I'm, Slim, Shady,real,lease stand up, the ".split`,`[x])

console.log(F())
```

Comment: Nice implementation :) You can save a byte by using a template literal in the `replace` function and replacing `\n` with an actual newline.

Comment: @Shaggy I could do better with template literals, but they where not implemented in any browser at time (Aug 2014)

Comment: Ah, I see. Does that invalidate [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116907/58974), so, seeing as this question was posted before the spec that defines template literals was standardised?

Comment: @Shaggy your answer is not invalid: `if there was no acceptable/legal interpreter for the language at the time the question was written, an answer may be submitted as non-competing`. (https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/21348)

Comment: Can someone explain how this works? Looks like magic to me.

Comment: @JacobPersi have a look

Answer (score 6):

## GolfScript, <s>162</s> <s>154</s> <s>152</s> 144 bytes

```c++
"I'm ":i"Slim ":|"Shady":y". Yes, "i"the real ":!y".
All you other "|y"s are just imitating.
So, won't "!|y" p""lease stand up":l"?
P"l". P"l"."
```

[Test online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IkknbSAiOmkiU2xpbSAiOnwiU2hhZHkiOnkiLiBZZXMsICJpInRoZSByZWFsICI6IXkiLgpBbGwgeW91IG90aGVyICJ8eSJzIGFyZSBqdXN0IGltaXRhdGluZy4KU28sIHdvbid0ICIhfHkiIHAiImxlYXNlIHN0YW5kIHVwIjpsIj8KUCJsIi4gUCJsIi4i)

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by replacing `\n` and `n` with an actual linefeeds and choosing non-alphanumeric variable names (e.g., `&`) to eliminate the whitespace around them.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks a lot! I edited my answer.

Comment: The war has begun.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam - 133

```
"I'm| Slim| Shady| the real|lease stand up|432. Yes, 412.
All you other32s are just imitating.
So, won't132 p0?
P0. P0."'|/~5,{`/\*}/
```

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

I think it also works in GolfScript if you replace `'|` with `"|"`

Comment: *All you other thirty-twos are just imitating. So, won't one three two pee ze-ro? Pee ze-ro. Pee ze-ro.* That's how it's gonna sound in my head from now on. :P

Answer (score 5):

**VBA 343 bytes**

```
Sub EMINEM()
e = "Slim "
m = "Shady"
i = "I'm "
n = "lease stand up"
em = "real "

MsgBox i & e & m & ". Yes, " & i & "the " & em & m & "." & Chr(10) & "All you other " & e & m & "s are just imitating." & Chr(10) & "So, won't the " & em & e & m & " p" & n & Chr(10) & "P" & n & ". P" & n & "."

End Sub
```

Comment: Very Nice implementation

Comment: Thanks Malachi, can't skip this golf as an old fans of Eminem.

Comment: I am working on one right now.

Comment: I am interested to see another approach!  Maybe ascii?

Comment: I could corner the market and port my C# to VB

Comment: Looking forward to it!

Comment: It's great to see someone golfing in VBA. Can't you print to the immediate window with `?` though?

Comment: @ckuhn203 "?" changes to 'print' but i'll need debug.print so it screw up everytime i use "?".  Feel free to point out if I can do it here, thanks!

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35564/20807

Answer (score 5):

## C# <s>209</s> <s>205</s> <s>201</s> <s>197</s> <s>209</s>  <s>212</s>  217

```
class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write("{0}{1}{2}. Yes, {0}{3}{2}.\nAll you other {1}{2}s are just imitating.\nSo, won't {3}{1}{2} p{4}?\nP{4}. P{4}.", "I'm ","Slim ","Shady","the real ","lease stand up");}}
```

*Now with Proper Capitalization and New Lines*

Comment: You could probably save some more chars by moving spaces from format string to replacements, like `WriteLine("{0}{1}","I'm ","Slim ")`.

Comment: The ending newline doesn't seem to be a requirement, so consider using `.Write()` instead of `.WriteLine()`. Even if it's required, `.Write()` with a `\n` is shorter.

Comment: thank you @Bob that saved me another 4 byes! even on my VB answer too!

Comment: You don't have capital P's on the Please Stand up twice

Comment: @TopinFrassi, I fixed it on this answer and on my VB answer as well.  I was also missing a space.  I am asking about the new lines in the output right now...

Answer (score 5):

## VB <s>253</s> <s>249</s> <s>245</s> <s>241</s> <s>244</s> <s>285</s> <s>259</s> 223

I hate New Line termination

```vb
Module M
Sub Main
Console.Write("{0}{1}{2}. Yes, {0}{3}{2}.{5}All you other {1}{2}s are just imitating.{5}So, won't {3}{1}{2} p{4}?{5}P{4}. P{4}.","I'm ","Slim ","Shady","the real ","lease stand up",vbCr)
End Sub
End Module
```

*Now with proper Capitalization And Newlines in the output, and no Tabs* *

***Thank you VB for `vbCrLf`***

[Thank you, @Taylor Scott!](https://tio.run/##JY@9asNAEIR7PcWgxglIInHi2gSTIoXAoCK4XEWLfeZ0a@7Hxhz37MpJavZjdmcZ5q5cIF335NRfbdjXoxiZplaGoBlt0YUeLSlTHMQ40dz8WuX5pYxvKb6nuE0NTuwqzPpj0XGXvrTGUwLEX9hi9TmQZVyD81Cj8uSVOc/eTio8xGw85v/Filv8TPt8O2Y2WGZZlT@bERmdVisvNDwzcwYsk553mskxnCczINzK6t4f7GvxnVXusXAtNk3/)

Comment: I wonder if this will run without the tabs and new lines?????

Comment: it won't let me in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: [223 Bytes](https://tio.run/##JY@9asNAEIR7PcWgxglIInHi2gSTIoXAoCK4XEWLfeZ0a@7Hxhz37MpJavZjdmcZ5q5cIF335NRfbdjXoxiZplaGoBlt0YUeLSlTHMQ40dz8WuX5pYxvKb6nuE0NTuwqzPpj0XGXvrTGUwLEX9hi9TmQZVyD81Cj8uSVOc/eTio8xGw85v/Filv8TPt8O2Y2WGZZlT@bERmdVisvNDwzcwYsk553mskxnCczINzK6t4f7GvxnVXusXAtNk3/)

Comment: @TaylorScott, apparently it will allow you to code it without the indentations now. or maybe that is just Mono for you

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes, what the compiler can parse is heavily dependent on what version you are on - especially heading back to VB 6.0 and prior

Answer (score 5):

## VBA 307 Bytes

And obfuscated with line separators (just for fun). Based on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35556/20807)

```
Function p()
e = "Slim ": m = "Shady": i = "I'm ": n = "lease stand up": s = "real ": a = "."
p = i & e & m & ". Yes, " & i & "the " & s & m & a & Chr(10) & "All you other " & e & m & "s are just imitating." & Chr(10) & "So, won't the " & s & e & m & " p" & n & Chr(10) & "P" & n & ". P" & n & a
End Function
```

Called from the immediate window with `?p`.

The 307 includes the `?p`.

Comment: Oh, ?P in immediate window I see, +1

Comment: you should get rid of `a = "."` I think you could shave off a few Bytes

Comment: Actually, on second thought, I think it's *more* readable with the line seperators vs new lines...

Comment: can't you get rid of the spaces between operators?

Comment: @Malachi according to the spec, yes, but actual implementations force the whitespace on you. If I did it in VBScript instead I could probably shorten it up a bit.

Comment: Would you save bytes by assigning a variable to `Chr(10)`?

Comment: No @cairdcoinheringaahing. I considered that when I first golfed this, but the variable & line separator would be just as many chars. *Maybe* one saved?

Answer (score 5):

## PHP - 151 bytes

```
<?="I'm Slim Shady".gzinflate("]Œ1
„0E{Á;üÎFr…ÅÒNHe9à°F&‰d&,Þ~Avmßûï;Ì¬=Æ.ÂVFaø•–ÃµÍ ‚#WäÓx    ñR
*Œ­ª!Ä`d!½Ï¹Ï=>9uöót7Ø…Ij”ÔýÕ6Ó?qx‚/");@realstand;
```

hexdump:

```
0000000 3f3c 223d 2749 206d 6c53 6d69 5320 6168
0000010 7964 2e22 7a67 6e69 6c66 7461 2865 5d22
0000020 318c 840a 1030 7b45 3bc1 cefc 7246 c585
0000030 4ed2 6548 e039 46b0 8926 2664 de2c 057e
0000040 7641 df6d effb cc3b 3dac 2ec6 56c2 6146
0000050 f812 9695 b5c3 20cd 2382 e457 14d3 0978
0000060 52f1 2a0a ad8c 21aa 60c4 2164 cfbd cfb9
0000070 3e3d 7539 f3f6 3774 85d8 1949 946a d416
0000080 d5fd d336 713f 8278 222f 3b29 7240 6165
0000090 736c 6174 646e 003b
0000097
```

## Another answer without using gzinflate (228 bytes):

Reads shorts (16 bits), extracts 3 5-bit integers as indices of a lookup table.

```
<?$a=str_split(" .Yes,AlyouthrajimngSw'pP?
")+[27=>"I'm ",'Slim ',@Shady,'the real ','lease stand up'];$b=unpack(@v26,'o…~:tç       (ƒ-4€t£9ê`0BË-SBT $2U`Y{ÿXg |ác');foreach($b as$c)echo$a[$c>>10],$a[$c>>5&31],$a[$c&31];
```

hexdump:

```
0000000 3f3c 6124 733d 7274 735f 6c70 7469 2228
0000010 2e20 6559 2c73 6c41 6f79 7475 7268 6a61
0000020 6d69 676e 7753 7027 3f50 220a 2b29 325b
0000030 3d37 223e 2749 206d 2c22 5327 696c 206d
0000040 2c27 5340 6168 7964 272c 6874 2065 6572
0000050 6c61 2720 272c 656c 7361 2065 7473 6e61
0000060 2064 7075 5d27 243b 3d62 6e75 6170 6b63
0000070 4028 3276 2c36 9d27 026f 8504 7e0c 3a03
0000080 e774 0918 0901 8328 1c2d 8034 a374 ea39
0000090 6001 3011 cb42 532d 5442 a007 3224 6055
00000a0 9d59 ff7b 5802 2067 e17c 2763 3b29 6f66
00000b0 6572 6361 2868 6224 6120 2473 2963 6365
00000c0 6f68 6124 245b 3e63 313e 5d30 242c 5b61
00000d0 6324 3e3e 2635 3133 2c5d 6124 245b 2663
00000e0 3133 3b5d
00000e4
```

Answer (score 5):

## C, 374

By moving memory

Not the shortest but can it get any faster?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *s;
void m (int d, int f, int p)
{
    memmove (s+p+f, s+p, strlen(s)-p+1); // Shift a part of the string to make room for our insertion
    memcpy (s+p, s+d, f); // Copy the desired reference in place
}
int main ()
{
    s = malloc (168);
    strcpy (s,"I'm Slim Shady. Yes, the real.\nAll you others are just imitating.\nSo, won't the please stand up?\nP. ");

    m (0, 4, 21);
    m (8, 6, 33);
    m (3, 11, 54);
    m (28, 5, 100);
    m (3, 11, 105);
    m (118, 14, 135);
    m (134, 16, 151);
    puts (s);
}
```

It's 374 chars long after minification.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char*s;void m(int d,int f,int p){memmove(s+p+f,s+p,strlen(s)-p+1);memcpy(s+p,s+d,f);}int main(){s=malloc(168);strcpy(s,"I'm Slim Shady. Yes, the real.\nAll you others are just imitating.\nSo, won't the please stand up?\nP. ");m(0,4,21);m(8,6,33);m(3,11,54);m(28,5,100);m(3,11,105);m(118,14,135);m(134,16,151);puts(s);}
```

Comment: Nice, but you can golf it down to 278 bytes: `char s[168]="I'm Slim Shady. Yes, the real.\nAll you others are just imitating.\nSo, won't the please stand up?\nP. ";m(d,f,p){memmove(s+p+f,s+p,strlen(s)-p+1);memcpy(s+p,s+d,f);}main(){m(0,4,21);m(8,6,33);m(3,11,54);m(28,5,100);m(3,11,105);m(118,14,135);m(134,16,151);puts(s);}`

Answer (score 5):

## Java, 247

My first code golf, while learning Java. Posted it because it beats the other (fully functional) Java entry and the Haskell entry.

```
class S{public static void main(String[]a){String s="I'm",t=" Slim",u=" Shady",v=" the real",w="lease stand up";System.out.print(s+t+u+". Yes, "+s+v+u+".\nAll you other"+t+u+"s are just imitating.\nSo, won't"+v+t+u+" p"+w+"?\nP"+w+". P"+w+".");}}
```

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell <s>194</s> <s>189</s> 164

```
"{0}{1}{2}. Yes, {0}{3}{2}.`nAll you other {1}{2}s are just imitating.`nSo, won't {3}{1}{2} p{4}?`nP{4}. P{4}."-f"I'm ","Slim ","Shady","the real ","lease stand up"
```

Somehow my answer ened up resembling [@nneonneo's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35531/3970) a lot, even though it wasn't my original intent...

Comment: [Changing \n to line breaks save three bytes](https://tio.run/##JY09C8MgGIT3/IrDxcWGfu2lY7dCpo5C3lbLmxjUEIL4261Jl3u4446b3EI@GGIuRaRjTqeczrnFi4LC5i@7b@7MWN0MFw15/FsB2hO@c4iwg4062vHTNp1TWNwoI7btXsSUrvnWPKu22FUc3uIhBwglO7YDZKXR/VpZD@BJ85Yx6UAIUY895kmW8gM "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## Lua <s>201</s> <s>193</s> <s>188</s> 178

```
h=" Shady"i="I'm"s=" Slim"..h r=" the real"u="lease stand up"io.write(i,s,". Yes, ",i,r,h,".\nAll you other",s,"s are just imitating.\nSo, won't",r,s," p",u,"?\nP",u,". P",u,".")
```

Ungolfed & expanded some

```
h=" Shady"
i="I'm"
s=" Slim"..h
r=" the real"
u="lease stand up"
io.write(i,s,". Yes, ",i,r,h,".\nAll you other",s,"s are just imitating.\nSo, won't",r,s," p",u,"?\nP",u,". P",u,".")
```

Answer (score 3):

**PYTHON: <s>198</s> 193 bytes**

```
i,s,h,r,t="I'm ","Slim ","Shady","real ","lease stand up"
print i+s+h+". Yes, "+i+"the "+r+h+".\nAll you other "+s+h+"s are just imitating.\nSo, won't the "+r+s+h+" p"+t+"?\n"+"P"+t+'. P'+t+'.'
```

Comment: move `please` into the variable holding `stand up` and get rid of your `g` variable, and possibly remove `/n` you don't need them

Comment: If I remove the \n the newlines will be gone, and I presume those are necessary for the output.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP - <strike>196</strike> 171

```
<?$S="Shady";$P="lease stand up";$R="the real ";$I="I'm ";$s="Slim ";echo"$I$s$S. Yes, $I$R$S
All you other $s$S"."s are just imitating.
So, won't $R$s$S p$P?
P$P. P$P."
```

;

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 161 <s>164</s> bytes

Not quite as short as [squeamish ossifrage's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35516/the-real-slim-shady#answer-35525), but I wanted to share the CamelCaseCompression, which no one else has used and allows the removal of many spaces and quotation marks.

It does need a slightly longer text to become truly beneficial, though.

```
$_="0 1 2. Yes, 03 2.
AllYouOther 1 2sAreJustImitating.
So, won't3 1 24?
4. 4.";s/\d/qw(I'm Slim Shady TheReal PleaseStandUp)[$&]/ge;s/\B([A-Z])/ \L\2/g;print
```

Edit: Following Thaylon's suggestion, the `s/(\S)([A-Z])/\1 \L\2/g` substitution has been shortened by four characters. That doesn't pick up on comma-capital digraphs, though, so an extra space had to be inserted before "won't".

Comment: Interesting. A bit shorter with "not a word boundary": s/\B([A-Z])/ \L\1/g;

Comment: Thanks @Thaylon. \B is something I'm going to have to read about. It's weird.

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, 197

```
(let((a"I'm ")(b"Slim ")(c"Shady")(d"real ")(e"lease stand up"))(format t"~{~A~}"(list a b c". Yes, "a"the "d c".
All you other "b c"s are just imitating.
So, won't the "d b c" p"e"?
P"e". P"e"")))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript - 140 (tweetable)

```
"I'm"" Slim"" Shady"". Yes, "3$" the real"3$".
All you other"6$2$"s are just imitating.
So won't"5$3$3$" p""lease stand up""?
P"1$". P"1$"."
```

I'm Slim Shady. Yes, 3 the real 3.

All you other 62s are just imitating.

So won't 533 please stand up?

P1. P1.

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 131 bytes

```
/0/ Shady//1/lease stand up//2/ the real//3/ Slim0//4/I'm/43. Yes, 420.
All you other3s are just imitating.
So, won't23 p1?
P1. P1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxCoMwFIXh3ac4m4vkqHEvHbsVnDpe8FJTohFvRHz61OHfvt@i2KxWCltinGW6yI5RxRSWZZ1wbGRP5Fmxq0TS3zCGpSUHvuqFg3f4qDUY@tZVzxhxpQPpHnZvkF3xOywjLCFLDuvXVWNqcKa1zr3H1j2qd@dwV8of)

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) (full program), <s>183</s> <s>180</s> <s>178</s> <s>173</s> 172 bytes

*178 -> 173 bytes, thanks to Sara J*

```rust
fn main(){print!("{}{}{}. Yes, {0}{}{2}.
All you other{1}{2}s are just imitating.
So, won't{3}{1}{2} p{}?
P{4}. P{4}.","I'm"," Slim"," Shady"," the real","lease stand up")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzNCsIwEITvfYoxl1Yoxb@7ePQm9ORxodFG0qQkW6SEPHtMLAuzM8PwucVzSi@DiZRp9mF2yvCuESGW6/CUvkU4lHSKXXXTGqtdYHmULhxL6UFO4pM5UJNiYmXeXdXbFl9rag7nuO0wh3itHuGSqX8VrbjXU1b0Wm1/pGEtJtPhJOnstSQv4ZnMgGUW@5jSDw)

Comment: [173 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYy9CsMwDIT3PIXqJQmY0L@tQ@nYrZCpoyBu4@LYwVYoQfjZXbtBcLo7js8vgVJ6WZhQ26bl2WtLu0ZwLNfBUwUJvC/pGLvqZgysbgFHo/J8KGUA9Ao@mQN60oSk7bureifh62xNfIrbDmaO1@rB50z9q5DiXk9ZoTd6@yMOazGZDl6hyd4oDAoCoR1gmUV7iSn9AA)

Comment: @SaraJ Ofc, obviously! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <del>308</del> <del>301</del> <del>298</del> <del>292</del> 258

Java is a bit verbose, but here is my try:

```
class P{public static void main(String[]c){String s=" Shady",t=" the real",l="lease stand up",i=" Slim",m="I'm";System.out.format("%s%s%s. Yes, %s%s%s.\nAll you other%s%ss are just imitating.\nSo, won't%s%s%s p%s?\nP%s. P%s.",m,i,s,m,t,s,i,s,t,i,s,l,l,l);}}
```

Comment: You can 1-merge 'real' and 'the', they're always together 2-move some blanks out of the big format string 3-above all: use more single variables, the a array is of no use. All in all you can go to ~270

Comment: @edc65 I didn't know that I could declare multiple strings in Java without writing `String` multiple times. That's why I had the array for all but one variable. Thanks a lot for the hints.

Answer (score 2):

## C# 226

```
class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write("{0}{1}{2}. Yes, {0} the{3} {2}.All you other{1}{2}s are just imitating.So, won't the{3}{1}{2} please{4}up?Please{4}up. Please{4}up.","I'm"," Slim ","Shady"," real"," stand ");}}
```

Comment: you missed some spots where you can remove a bunch of characters, check mine out.  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35557/9435

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL: <strike>273</strike> 267**

```
set @i="I'm", @s="Slim", @h="Shady", @r="real", @t="stand", @p="lease stand up";select concat(@i," ",@s," ",@h,". Yes, ",@i," the ",@r," ",@h,".\r\nAll you other ",@s," ",@h,"s are just imitating.\r\nSo, won't the ",@r," ",@s," ",@h," p",@p,"?\r\nP",@p,". P",@p,".");
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby: 211

This one is impressive since simply printing the text is more efficient, but this is way cooler.

```
puts Zlib.inflate("eJxdjDEKwzAQBHu9Yjs3Rl8ILt0FVKU88GErnCWhO2H8e6sIwUmzxQyz87AjSOyz0XJ6vFhHzB3axqhM8hFuEsGZG3IX9ZYoqDLeTQ1xj0YW0+pdyCOOnAa7/XwTFGFShhqlBa083PMXePyDC15NOP8=".unpack("m0")[0])#I'mSlimShadyrealstand
```

Answer (score 2):

## F#, <strike>250</strike> 242

```
[1..21]|>List.iter((function|1|5->"I'm "|2|9|13->"Slim "|4->". Yes, "|6|12->"the real "|8->".\nAll you other "|11->"s are just imitating.\nSo won't "|15->" p"|16|18|20-> "lease stand up"|17->"?\nP"|19->". P"|21->"."|_->"Shady")>>printf "%s")
```

More readable version with line breaks:

```
[1..21]|>List.iter((function
|1|5->"I'm "
|2|9|13->"Slim "
|4->". Yes, "
|6|12->"the real "
|8->".\nAll you other "
|11->"s are just imitating.\nSo won't "
|15->" p"
|16|18|20-> "lease stand up"
|17->"?\nP"
|19->". P"
|21->"."
|_->"Shady")>>printf "%s")
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript <s>259</s> <s>240</s> 238 bytes

Not that good but might as well post an answer.

```
b=String.prototype,b.a=b.replace,alert("123. Yes, 16537All you other 23s are just imitating7So, won't 6523 p4?\nP4. P4.".a(/1/g,"I'm ").a(/2/g,"Slim ").a(/3/g,"Shady").a(/4/g,"lease stand up").a(/5/g,"real ").a(/6/g,"the ").a(/7/g,".\n"))
```

More readable version :

```
b=String.prototype
b.a=b.replace
alert("123. Yes, 16537All you other 23s are just imitating7So, won't 6523 p4?\nP4. P4."
    .a(/1/g,"I'm ")
    .a(/2/g,"Slim ")
    .a(/3/g,"Shady")
    .a(/4/g,"lease stand up")
    .a(/5/g,"real ")
    .a(/6/g,"the ")
    .a(/7/g,".\n")
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 179 Bytes

```php
<?
$i="I'm";
$s=" Slim";
$h=" Shady";
$p="lease stand up";
$r=" the real";
echo"$i$s$h. Yes, $i$r$h.\nAll you other$s$h"."s are just imitating.\nSo, won't$r$s$h p$p?\nP$p. P$p.";
```

And golfed

```php
<?$i="I'm";$s=" Slim";$h=" Shady";$p="lease stand up";$r=" the real";echo"$i$s$h. Yes, $i$r$h.\nAll you other$s$h"."s are just imitating.\nSo, won't$r$s$h p$p?\nP$p. P$p.";
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>165</s> 163 bytes

```js
f=

_=>`${a="I'm"}${b=` Slim${c=` Shady`}`}. Yes, ${a+(d=" the real")+c}.
All you other${b}s are just imitating.
So, won't${d+b} p${e="lease stand up"}?
P${e}. P${e}.`

console.log(f());
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab 206 bytes

```
i='I''m ';s='Slim ';h='Shady';r=' real ';t=' stand ';p=['Please' t 'up. '];sprintf([i s h '. Yes, ' i 'the' r h '.\nAll you other ' s h 's are just imitating.\nSo, won''t the' r s h ' please' t 'up?.\n' p p])
```

Comment: Found a typo: `h ' are` should become `h 's are`. -- You could also save a little by changing `up.` to `up. ` so you don't need the `' '` near the end.

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 197 bytes

```
printf"%A"<|System.String.Format("{0}{1}{2}. Yes, {0}{3}{2}.\nAll you other {1}{2}s are just imitating.\nSo, won't {3}{1}{2} p{4}?\nP{4}. P{4}.","I'm ","Slim ","Shady","the real ","lease stand up")
```

## F#, 210 bytes (alternate method)

```
let a,b,c,d,e="I'm ","Slim ","Shady","the real ","lease stand up"
printf"%s"<|a+b+c+". Yes, "+a+d+c+".\nAll you other "+b+c+"s are just imitating.\nSo, won't "+d+b+c+" p"+e+"?\nP"+e+". P"+e+"."
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java - 204

**Ungolfed**:

```
String i = "I'm", s = " Slim", h = " Shady", r = " the real", t = "lease stand up";
System.out.printf(i + s + h + ". Yes, " + i + r + h + ".%n"
        + "All you other " + s + h + "s are just imitating.%n"
        + "So, won't" + r + h + " p" + t + "?%n"
        + "P" + t + ". P" + t + ".");
```

**Golfed**:

```
String i="I'm",s=" Slim",h = " Shady",r =" the real",t="lease stand up";System.out.printf(i+s+h+". Yes, "+i+r+h+".%nAll you other"+s+h+"s are just imitating.%nSo, won't"+r+h+" p"+t+"?%nP"+t+". P"+t+".");
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <del>250</del> 221 bytes

Hell it beats the java version, so I'm posting. Is this really as good as it gets, or is there some secret function or monad or something that would make this task easier to complete succinctly?

**Edit**: I used `intercalcate " "` instead of `unwords`...

```haskell
putStr$let i="I'm";s="Slim";h="Shady";r="the real";p="lease stand up";d=".";n='\n';in unwords[i,s,h++d,"Yes,",i,r,h++d,n:"All you other",s,h++"s","are just imitating"++d,n:"So, won't",r,s,h,'p':p++"?",n:'P':p++d,'P':p++d]
```

Comment: I just posted a Java entry which beats your Haskell entry. Thought you might want to know ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Dart - 178 characters

Plain string interpolation and variables.

```dart
main({i:"I'm ",r:"the real ",s:"Slim ",z:"Shady",t:"lease stand up"}){print("$i$s$z. Yes, $i$r$z.\nAll you other $s${z}s are just imitating.\nSo, won't $r$s$z p$t?\nP$t. P$t.");}
```

Fiddling with whitespace can get it down to 176:

```dart
main({i:"I'm",r:" the real",s:" Slim",z:" Shady",t:"lease stand up"}){print("$i$s$z. Yes, $i$r$z.\nAll you other$s${z}s are just imitating.\nSo, won't$r$s$z p$t?\nP$t. P$t.");}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure - 255 chars

Simple solution from a Clojure newbie. Golfed:

```
(defn p[f & x](println(apply format f x)))(let[i "I'm" s "Shady" l "Slim" e "lease stand up" r "the real"](p "%s %s %s. Yes, %s %s %s." i l s i r s)(p "All you other %s %ss are just imitating." l s)(p "So, won't %s %s %s p%s?" r l s e)(p "P%s. P%s." e e))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defn p [f & x] (println (apply format f x)))
(let [i "I'm" s "Shady" l "Slim" e "lease stand up" r "the real"]
    (p "%s %s %s. Yes, %s %s %s." i l s i r s)
    (p "All you other %s %ss are just imitating." l s)
    (p "So, won't %s %s %s p%s?" r l s e)
    (p "P%s. P%s." e e))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 191

Pretty basic attempt:

```
alert((a="I'm")+(b=" Slim")+(c=" Shady")+". Yes, "+a+" the "+(d="real")+c+".\nAll you other"+b+c+"s are just imitating.\nSo, won't the "+d+b+c+" p"+(e="lease stand up")+"?\nP"+e+". P"+e+".");
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 165

Paste directly in the intermediate pane.

```
i="I'm":s=" Slim Shady":r=" the real":p="lease stand up":?i+s". Yes, "i+r+mid(s,6)".":?"All you other"s"s are just imitating.":?"So, won't"r+s" p"p"?":?"P"p". P"p"."
```

Major golfing comes from the quirky properties of VBA's intermediate pane's ? command.  You can place a string variable followed immediately by a string literal and they will concatenate with no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## Pure bash, 156 bytes

Nothing especially exciting here:

```
f()(echo "$1$2$3. Yes, $1$4$3.
All you other $2$3s are just imitating.
So, won't $4$2$3 ${5,}?
$5. $5.")
f "I'm " Slim\  Shady "the real " "Please stand up"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>186</s> 181 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

```c
f(){char*a=" Slim Shady",*c="I'm the real";printf("%.3s%s. Yes, %s%s.\nAll you other%ss are just imitating.\nSo, won't%s%s p%s?\nP%8$s. P%8$s.",c,a,c,a+5,a,c+3,a,"lease stand up");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY8xC8IwEIVn@yuOYGir0aUIQhFxdBM6CV2ONLaRNC25FBHxt8cEh3fvDd8d9@SulzKER1F@5IBugycGjdEjNAN2byY28sSu@Qh@UOAUGlbPTlv/KBjfV8RpD3dFAniKrb0YA@9pgSnijhMBOgXPhTzoUXv02vaRaiYBr8nmPm3BzOnc2hs/ruOxvzEhBSZtD8m3VZzMKCQF5NF2sMysrL8hPgIjaluU2SdbxQ519g0/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/), 166 bytes

```py
a,b,c,d="I'm","Slim Shady","the real","lease stand up"
print(a,b+". Yes,",a,c,b[5:]+".\nAll you other",b+"s are just imitating.\nSo, won't",c,b,f"p{d}?\nP{d}. P{d}.")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HUw9C8IwEN39FcctVQxdxEUQcXQTOol1uJpoI2kSkitSxN8ery7vi/denLgPflMKqU7dld7jqRpQYePsAE1PehLDvYFkyIl0hrKBzOQ1jBEXMVnPSxmvsYaLyQoVyU933e5uErX@6BxMYYQgJwnnXgZKBl5jZrCDZWLrn1JsgoJ38BXjvFcPjB/9PbT@LFTDH3FVyg8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>116</s> <s>115</s> <s>112</s> 97 bytes

```
═Φ-cgvUV;Mc╔&♠◘Aτö,↔↕■∙o→¬▬⌡♪╓B▒ε,æO5≤,╝2Æ;╗)▀ìc)E]«╬ôÅ∩╖╚d:☻╔╩2Ñs*çφIBë╕gpÜI'mSlimShadyrealstand
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=cde82d63677655563b4d63c926060841e7942c1d12fef96f1aaa16f50dd642b1ee2c914f35f32cbc32923bbb29df8d6329455daece938fefb7c8643a02c9ca32a5732a87ed494289b867709a49276d536c696d53686164797265616c7374616e64&i=&a=1)

*All credit to this answer to Khuldraeseth na'Barya.  I originally had a solution, but it's been completely re-written with none of the original now.*

Stax programs have two representations.  Pure ASCII and "packed".  Packed stax uses all 256 byte values, and thus is smaller than ASCII, which uses only 95.  This solution is particularly clever because it's packed code that contains the required words.  When unpacked, the `I'mSlimShadyrealstand` roughly becomes `"j|ksRfwb)ys\\GP*vOyn@[<a\\"d` which is a no-op.  The rest of the program is pretty straight-forward compressed string literals.

Comment: Compress the whole darn thing and use a comment for [112 bytes](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%60%3DrmN%29%233maM%2Bea8%7C,]w+s%60P%6078pNzx,Z%212Y6,K4dU6%3F%3F1mrM%60P%6072,L%3AhSlP%2B39%7ES6qj.RLmVmo%60P%60%3B%22tyPuw%2B%21%60qP%09I%27mSlimShadyrealstand&i=&a=1).

Comment: Wow,  That's so simple.  I love it.

Comment: Kinda makes me wonder. The site doesn't allow packing of tabs, but some meddling with TS yields a packing of `"\t<c>"` that unpacks to `"h<c-1>"`. Might it be possible to pack a tab in such a way that unpacking preserves it and that arbitrary characters can be inserted somewhere in the packed version?

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya:  I think you're on to something.  Two ascii programs with the same length that share some suffix will share a *prefix* in their packed representation.  I don't think tabs are going to be able to help, but I think it might be possible to embed the words in the midst of an ignored string literal when unpacked.

[Here](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/4a20b37fe55d7029d5dbea16dde803b4e15c05b5/StaxLang.JS/packer.ts#L62) is the unpacking code used by the "web app".

Comment: [Got it!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=cde82d63677655563b4d63c926060841e7942c1d12fef96f1aaa16f50dd642b1ee2c914f35f32cbc32923bbb29df8d6329455daece938fefb7c8643a02c9ca32a5732a87ed494289b867709a49276d536c696d53686164797265616c7374616e64&i=&a=1) This can likely be shortened by removing the `d`, but it's an improvement nevertheless.

Comment: I'm dumbfounded right now. As far as I can tell, getting that necessary `"` character (and without something before it that would break execution or output!) was pure luck.

Comment: Wow, that was very quick work.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>168</s> 160 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

```r
`[`=gsub;cat(1["I'm",2[" Slim ",3["Shady",4[" the real",5["lease stand up","123. Yes, 14 3.
All you other23s are just imitating.
So, won't423 p5?
P5. P5."]]]]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYs9C4MwGAZ3f8XDu9hCCJjoVErp2K3gVELBtAa1RCP5oPjrU3twy8H5nDvVnYeQXqe3jodK0a2ciQlFaO00g5hU1I6634jVe4yjgTfaEmsUWaODQYh66ZFWYlQJyfEwgaGqIXlxtRabS3D75oUM0N7gk0LENE9Rx2kZeNE6hq9bylgLibW5FPeGY5eef445/wA)

Comment: Using `\`[\``, we can get to [160](https://tio.run/##FYs9C4MwGAZ3f8XDu9hCCJjoVErp2K3gVELBtAa1RCP5oPjrU3twy8H5nDvVnYeQXqe3jodK0a2ciQlFaO00g5hU1I6634jVe4yjgTfaEmsUWaODQYh66ZFWYlQJyfEwgaGqIXlxtRabS3D75oUM0N7gk0LENE9Rx2kZeNE6hq9bylgLibW5FPeGY5eef445/wA)

Comment: @Giuseppe It must be your life goal to improve on every answer I give... Oh well. I'll update it.

Comment: No, I was just not very active on CCGC for a while, so I've been trying to catch up by going through the profiles of the R golfers I know to look for neat tricks, suggest improvements, and help foster community. :-)

Comment: Ah, so that's why I was able to actually get some answers posted before the real master showed up.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 154 bytes

```bash
set "I'm" Slim Shady real stand
<<.
$1${6= $2 $3}. Yes, $1 the $4 $5.
All you other$6s are just imitating.
So, won't the $4$6 p${x=lease $5 up}?
P$x. P$x.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7PCoJAHITv-xSD_MCLLfRH6aBEx26Cp4gOC25prG64u6RFL1IXIeqdepuKvMwwHwx898fZFK-NN0q9bf90djeav29GWngrv_KQqbJCVoi8QyOFgrGizlkcc0ZjukQJaAKaXjnW0gSgMWwhQTNQyNlSKXTaQX9ZQ5GBaCQOzliUVWmFLes9Z5kOcNK1b4cnRTjSpU2UFOa7Q7jjdcFSajl-8TccRPuhPw)

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy - 196 chars

Pretty basic solution:

```
i="I'm"
s="Shady"
l="Slim"
p="lease stand up"
q="P$p."
r="the real"
f={println it}
f "$i $l $s. Yes, $i $r $s."
f "All you other $l ${s}s are just imitating."
f "So, won't $r $l $s p$p?"
f "$q $q"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python: 175

Just a small change to the answer by **nneonneo**, but i can't comment and there don't seem to be private messages on this website so i'll post it this way.

```
a="Slim Shady"
print"{0}{1}. Yes, {0}{3}{2}.\nAll you other {1}s are just imitating.\nSo, won't {3}{1} p{4}?\nP{4}. P{4}.".format("I'm ",a,a[5:],"the real ","lease stand up")
```

Answer (score 0):

### FASM 212 bytes

```
z fix equ
A z "I'm "
C z "Shady"
D z "the real "
E z "Slim ",C
F z "Please stand up"
N=$A
L z ". "
display A,E,L,"Yes, ",A,D,C,L,N,"All you other ",E,"s are just imitating.",N,"So, won't ",D,E," ",F,"?",N,F,L,F,L
```

Comment: Wouldn't this capitalise the first `Please` as well?

Answer (score 0):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/) - 195

```
{S~&I'm&}{I~& Slim&&M}{M~& Shady&}{P~& the real&}{L~&Please&&E~&.&}{E~& stand up&}>&S&I~&. Yes, &&S&P&M~&.
All you other&&I~&s are just imitating.
So, won't&&P&I~& please&&E~&?
&&L~& &&L<[<]>[.>]
```

Everything pure BF is BF. `{name ...}` is a macro, `&name` applies macro and `~"string"` stores string in current position.`"` can be any char so I choose `&` to obfuscate it a little.

Comment: What's the point of extending Brainfuck? Doesn't that make it inherently less useful?

Comment: @feersum No, It allows for more abstraction. I made it as an exercise in bootstrapping so the compiler is written in itself and it compiles the code to BF. This was just a step towards the ultimate goal to make [LISP run on BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/) and it only took 3 summers from planning to something working. EBF wasn't designed to be used for golfing but I found out that some of it's features allow for compact code. If I ever make new versions it would be to support a kind of switch-case/if-else and not make it a better golf language.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP: 176

Thought I might as well give it a shot, nothing fancy though

```
$b="I'm ";$c="Slim";$d="Shady";$e="$c $d";$f="the real ";$g="lease stand up";echo"$b$e. Yes, $b$f$d.\nAll you other $e"."s are just imitating.\nSo, won't $f$e p$g?\nP$g. P$g.";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 188

```cobra
class P
    def main
        s,p=" Slim Shady","lease stand up"
        l,p="I'm[s]. Yes, I'm the real[s[5:]].\nAll you other[s]s are just imitating.\nSo, won't the real[s] p[p]?\n","P[p]."
        print l+p,p
```

Comment: Please explain how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript - <s>196</s> 182

```
s="I'm ",l="Slim Shady",m="the real ",r="lease stand up";alert(s+l+". Yes, "+s+m+l.slice(5)+".\nAll you other "+l+"s are just imitating.\nSo, won't "+m+l+" p"+r+"?\nP"+r+". P"+r+".")
```

If you want a explanation, just comment.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 185

```
alert((i="I'm")+(s=" Slim"+(h=" Shady"))+". Yes, "+i+(r=" the real")+h+".\n"+"All you other "+s+"s are just imitating.\n"+"So, won't"+r+s+" p"+(p="lease stand up")+"?\n"+"P"+p+". P"+p+".")
```

Answer (score 0):

## ///, <s>131</s> <s>132</s> 135 bytes

```
/!/lease stand up//#/ Shady//@/ Slim#//$/ real//%/I'm/%@. Yes, % the$#.
All you other@s are just imitating.
So, won't the$@ p!?
P!. P!.
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=LyEvbGVhc2Ugc3RhbmQgdXAvLyMvIFNoYWR5Ly9ALyBTbGltIy8vJC8gcmVhbC8vJS9JJ20vJUAuIFllcywgJSB0aGUkIy4KQWxsIHlvdSBvdGhlckBzIGFyZSBqdXN0IGltaXRhdGluZy4KU28sIHdvbid0IHRoZSRAIHAhPwpQIS4gUCEu&input=)

Answer (score 0):

### c, 214 byte

```
main(){char*k[]={"I'm ","Slim ","Shady","the real ","lease stand up"},*w="012. Yes, 032.\nAll you other 12s are just imitating.\nSo, won't 312 p4?\nP4. P4.",c;for(;*w;)c=*w++,c>47&&c<58?printf(k[c-48]):putchar(c);}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#JY9BC4IwHMW/yp8dSm2J2iLJTDp2CzpFehhr5XJusk0kos9uRofHDx6/d3hjS4Xy/DerqQmaa5W/0XHeAsLoLMWfNb29Jrqag@FU/jrJqeVgHVU36Dv0wcGQoyhOQrhwiyFaJWGpDlLCS/egp6WBOLFADYdnbx2IVjjqhHpM2lljGLSaO1jFCXSkKNWJhDAFYZbdtfGyYMh8lgfDYoHZnmxmM7Zbp0VnhHJ3r7myJUkrf9v17vfCY372Gccv)

Comment: [198 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYvNCoJAFEZf5TKL8i9RM4rMomXQImgV5WK4jjU1zsjMiIT07Ga0OBw4fB/O7ojD4L2uRd6Tw7QGEpCz4H8/aPkebR8MNKPi1wSjhoGxVJbQNuQTeF1@JFGchHBhJoBonoQ3uRcC3qoFNV41xIkBqhk8W2OB19xSy@V9nJ1VAJ2SUwvzOIEm3d3kKQ1hhGQ15dJBt6@UdjLMvc73s0ZzaSsHt@lygpvFave64ixdFesJum72GYYv "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## C, 220 bytes

```C
char*s="I'm",*h="Slim",*a="Shady",*d="real",*y="lease stand up";f(){printf("%s %s %s. Yes, %s the %s %s.\nAll you other %s %ss are just imitating.\nSo, won't the %s %s %s p%s?\nP%s. P%s.",s,h,a,s,d,a,h,a,d,d,h,a,y,y,y);}
```

**Detailed** [Live](http://ideone.com/mYI7gA)

```C
#include <stdio.h>

char  *  s  =  "I'm"             ;
char  *  h  =  "Slim"            ;
char  *  a  =  "Shady"           ;
char  *  d  =  "real"            ;
char  *  y  =  "lease stand up"  ;

f(){printf("%s %s %s. Yes, %s the %s %s.\n\\
All you other %s %ss are just imitating.\n\\
So, won't the %s %s %s p%s?\nP%s. P%s.",

    s,
        h,
            a,
    s,
                d,
            a,
        h,
            a,
                d,
                d,
        h,
            a,
                    y,
                    y,
                    y

);}int main(){f();return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 164 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that take no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
l=" Slim Shady":i="I'm":r=" the real":t="lease stand up":?i;s". Yes, "i;r;Mid(s,6)".":?"All you other"s" are just imitating.":?"So, won't"r;s" p"t"?":?"P"t". P"t".
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 166 bytes:

```php
<?=($i="I'm"),($l=" Slim".$s=" Shady"),". Yes, $i",($r="  the real"),"$s.
All you other${l}s are just imitating.
So, won't$r$l p",($p="lease stand up"),"?
P$p. P$p.";
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>152</s> 151 bytes

```
echo(0 :0)rplc'12345';"0'\'cut' Slim\ Shady\lease stand up\ the real\I''m'
512. Yes, 542.
All you other12s are just imitating.
So, won't412 p3?
P3. P3.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq7CoMwGAbQPU/x0eVvQYKJutShdOxWcCpkCRpqJBrJheLTpw5nO0spZpz9tca9voXdjSRk03bUX2pSNOZEGJxdFYZZT4dyRkeDmPQ2Ie8KaTYIRjv1IlqJdUJyfEys0LWSs6dzOHyGP1sQMkIHgyXHBLvapJPdvpwNvsLPb5RaIbE3D/ZuOE6l/AE)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 181 bytes (function)

```java
v->"".format("%s%s%s. Yes, %1$s%s%3$s.%nAll you other %2$s%3$ss are just imitating.%nSo, won't %4$s%2$s%3$s p%s?%nP%5$s. P%5$s.","I'm ","Slim ","Shady","the real ","lease stand up")
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LZBPS8QwEMXv@ykeoWFb6Ab8d1pUPHpwEQqCiIexze6mpklJ0kqR/ew1sSWQx8w8Jvm9lkba2V6atvmea03e44WU@d0AygTpjlRLHFIJVMEpc0Kdv1nVYCz2sXvZxMsHCqrGAQb3mMfdA2PiaF1HIWfcpyPwLn0JfpWl8ibzgpsnrTHZATacpQO/zv4HHuQk2sEHqE6lxeYUzZUt8WPNNoDfRuNqRs/9Izev/C5uxCKsZM/bDlEqrRY9UzNFje/ASdKppyV5mT5uGgw9K@Z9AumHLx1BVp4xYXYxjXwh//ikYk1i8kF2wg5B9HESciPq3AxaF2sol/kP)

## Java 8, 229 bytes (full program)

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.printf("%s%s%s. Yes, %1$s%s%3$s.%nAll you other %2$s%3$ss are just imitating.%nSo, won't %4$s%2$s%3$s p%s?%nP%5$s. P%5$s.","I'm ","Slim ","Shady","the real ","lease stand up");}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY/NasNADIRfZTBekoBj6N@ph9JjDoWCT6X0IGIlWXetNSs5xYQ8u7tuig4fGg0apqMzbePA0rXf8@zFOB1oz3i7qJH5Pc7Rt@jJy7qx5OX4@UWbSzOpcV/H0eohi3ZYF06XqfHBWsHdlcv6UGrt5DUETHFEtBMnuPvy76CgxOhGNfjeL1lyzOYmVviJsjK4x2z8N2Nw@uLk3T3lj7ihqIrdqkdGE/yNJ2qnzJyDxBQWLTApI3eRFuNQbJ6v13n@BQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 177 bytes

```
VAR i="I'm"
~temp s=" Slim"+w
VAR w=" Shady"
VAR r=" the real"
VAR l="lease stand up"
{i+s}. Yes, {i+r+w}.
All you other{s}s are just imitating.
So, won't{r+s} p{l}?
P{l}. P{l}.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy9CoMwHMT3PMWRxUHxDaQ4disVCh0Dhpo2H5J/JEhIXz2Ndjnud8edsp9SHuMdauDXxnD2DdKsoIFj0srwNrKjjQcvYt75ib5iWCS8FPqf6IFrKUiCgrAztpWzpFrKPZ6SOlTv25h7NmqN3W1wde4TZYLwEu@NApRRQQRlXz2bXIfobBOSrx9Yk84Xdqva49RSfg)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) 211 + class stuff etc = 255 bytes

```
public class p{public static void Main(){System.Console.WriteLine(@"{0}{1}{2}. Yes, {0}the {3}{2}.
All you other {1}{2}s  are just imitating.
So, won't the {3}{1}{2} please {4}up?
Please {4}up. Please {4}up.","I'm ","Slim ","Shady","real ","stand ");}}
```

This is probably as {1} as it gets ;)

I just the @ string tag instead of \r\n because thats 1 byte instead of 12 (3 * \r\n)
EDIT: Didn't know you needed the full class so here

Comment: You can get [229 bytes](https://tio.run/##LU89C8IwEN37K44uWqjBr81BxUlQEDqIY2wPG0mTkkuVEvLba9K6vA94d@@upEWpDQ5D2z2lKKGUnAha97dkuQ300aKCKxdqnrmiJ4sNO2lFWiK7G2HxIhTOD6lberfybu0ZPJByiH4z@uQoJfS6A21rNFOIgBuEd0cWRCNikXqxpNA5fLWa2Tg55sI1W79PbgEZjJjm6XnWBIRCiolrXvVRhPVgkMugJXLC@IGqoGvTbOf9MPwA) by moving some more words into the variables and shuffling the spaces around a bit.

Comment: [181 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYy7CoNAFER7v@Jio4KRvLpEE0kVSBGwCCk3eo0r667sXgki@@3GR3NmBmYmN5vc8DHNiSt5Vp8ac0qgjEcWJzcljRIYvTQnfHCJ/tUdtnbY2WFvI3ijCWHOhyU7qRDQqw4UVajXkgGmEerOEPCGEyMuv5GTqRB@Sno0L5cetMPRXpznxAgWuqF795qJkAm@asWKfjbTPWhkYvICmUEwxGQBXesG46n0ZSdEcBr/ "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online") by changing to using the Visual Interactive Compiler. By the way, class stuff and the main method are usually not counted toward the bytes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>124</s> 122 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"real"“‚µ stand€¾“"Shady""Slim"…I'm)•AΘ¥в‚Y•Sè`“ÿ ÿ ÿ.…Ü, ÿ€€ ÿ ÿ.
All€î€¶ ÿ ÿs€™‚‰ imitating.
So,¢²'t€€ ÿ ÿ ÿ ÿ?
ÿ. ÿ.“.ª
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fqSg1MUfpUcOcRw2zDm1VKC5JzEt51LTm0D6gkFJwRmJKpZJScE5mLlDJMk/1XM1HDYscz804tPTCJqCGSCAv@PCKBKDaw/sVwEgPqO7wHB0gC2gKEEFFuRxzcoC8w@tAZm@DCBaDVLQsAprzqGGDQmZuZkliSWZeuh5XcL7OoUWHNqmXIBsBQfZcQMMg1szRO7Tq/38A) or [verify that it's correct](https://tio.run/##XVDBisIwEL33K4ZcilDyC@LRm0tP3owYNEvaSJOyeCviR4j0VFBEZFmE3eMupPdlvyE/ohNbpCu8Q@bNmzdvojSbCn69kowzSVxRumJnP0Ebls7c@my/kSLxgs1WhMRSJCg5DMOk54pq8Lu1@78LDoyxiuvjBLX1D9xBUVeXEb7QBdGywUBKrOp37/3VkNorNhX6uOIDRCIMMyKd0yBWka3sJTRdiwb9AM2aNSW1pxc8gBDMBT4j3PNSGHMdgSfNgoO/r234ELBSOShsZJ0RDSzj8Jpr8xQD3lQamo7PYwSWkjPNmw@DfNkPRv8JCs8EJr0B).

**Explanation:**

```python
"real"              # Push string "real"
“‚µ stand€¾“        # Push dictionary string "please stand up"
"Shady"             # Push string "Shady"
"Slim"              # Push string "Slim"
…I'm               '# Push string "I'm"
)                   # Wrap all strings on the stack into a list:
                    #  ["real","please stand up","Shady","Slim","I'm"]
 •AΘ¥в‚Y•           # Push compressed integer 11123023204234
         S          # Converted to a list of digits: [1,1,1,2,3,0,2,3,2,0,4,2,3,4]
          è         # Index each into the string-list:
                    #  ["please stand up","please stand up","please stand up","Shady","Slim",
                    #   "real","Shady","Slim","Shady","real","I'm","Shady","Slim","I'm"]
           `        # Pop and push these strings separated to the stack
“ÿ ÿ ÿ.…Ü, ÿ€€ ÿ ÿ. # Push dictionary string "ÿ ÿ ÿ. yes, ÿ the ÿ ÿ.\n
All€î€¶ ÿ ÿs€™‚‰ imitating.
                    #                         All you other ÿ ÿs are just imitating.\n
So,¢²'t€€ ÿ ÿ ÿ ÿ? '#                         So, won't the ÿ ÿ ÿ ÿ?\n
ÿ. ÿ.“              #                         ÿ. ÿ."
                    # where the `ÿ` are automatically filled with the strings of the stack
      .ª            # And sentence capitalize every sentence
                    # (without disturbing existing uppercase letters)
                    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“‚µ stand€¾“` is `"please stand up"`; `•AΘ¥в‚Y•` is `11123023204234`; and `“ÿ ÿ ÿ.…Ü, ÿ€€ ÿ ÿ.\nAll€î€¶ ÿ ÿs€™‚‰ imitating.\nSo,¢²'t€€ ÿ ÿ ÿ ÿ?\nÿ. ÿ.“` is `"ÿ ÿ ÿ. yes, ÿ the ÿ ÿ.\nAll you other ÿ ÿs are just imitating.\nSo, won't the ÿ ÿ ÿ ÿ?\nÿ. ÿ."`.